# First 5 cells not showing image in custom TableView Cell - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a `UITableView` which I have transformed into horizontal tableview, and a  custom `UITableViewCell` which just has a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`

The problem is, first 5 cells don't show the images, but when I scroll and come back to them, images are shown. No idea what the problem is :(

(picture below, please see the horizontal tableview, ignore the vertical one)
[image]

Here's my code in TableViewController Class:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //Rotating the tableview angle -PI/2 Rad = -90 Degrees
    _friendsTableView.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);

    _friendsTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    CGRect frame = _friendsTableView.frame;
    frame.origin.y= _segmentControl.frame.size.height;
    frame.origin.x= 0;
    frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    frame.size.height = 105.5;
    _friendsTableView.frame= frame;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    FriendsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (nil == cell) {
            cell = [[FriendsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        }

        if(cell)
        {
            cell.user = cellsArray_[indexPath.row];
            cell.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);

        }
        return cell;
}
```

Now this is my custom cell class code where I set the image and label (`_user` is a property, so this setter method gets called automatically from `cell.user`):

```
-(void)setUser
{
    _profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = _profileImageView.frame.size.width/2;

    _user = user;

    _nameLabel.text = @"Hello";

    [_profileImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder_image"]];
}
```

Comment: where are you calling this method `setUser` ?

Comment: @SahebRoy sorry for the confusion, `user` is a property whose setter method gets automatically when `cell.user` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Collection View controller instead. Transforming Tableview controller seems not good.

In your code your are not calling your setUser method.

For Custom table view cell you can add following code in

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strID];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
              NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
}
```

Comment: i guess he just syntisized the _user inside the custom cell and when he call cell.user  = ... he calls the setUser automatically.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, `user` is a property whose setter method gets automatically when `cell.user` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

For my experience this is strictly related to the reusability of the Cells, i had a similar problem once, my solution is before assigning something to an IBOulet, make sure to have it empty, after that, assign it and it should work.